# Why Prisma introspection does not like my naming?

Tags: prisma

I try to introspect my existing DB to generate Prisma schema with

```
npx prisma db pull
```

I get a list of warnings like:

```
These enum values were commented out because their names are currently not supported by Prisma. 
Please provide valid ones that match [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* using the `@map` attribute:
  - Enum: "orderstatus_type", value: "0"
```

I don't see what's wrong with my naming. Is there something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints apply to both names and values. I suggest running `prisma db pull` first, then manually adjusting the schema after introspection.

You can create mappings like this:

```
enum OrderStatusType @@map("orderstatus_type"){
  Zero @map("0")
}
```

In this way, the generated type adheres to CamelCase and complies with the regex specified in the error message.

Comment: Problem is: the whole schema uses underscores after `db pull`. I'd like to have one notation all over, so introducing camelcase for one case seems odd

Comment: The camelcase is only for ease of use later [can be done all over the schema] obv you can omit it and just add the "Zero @map("0")" part